# Dictionary groupings and sum causes An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, group-by

I have a scenario where in case there is a specific boolean value satisfied (`office_debit_total` line) I can get amount directly from a column otherwise I need to calculate it by grouping some specific values, here's the code:

```
var result = products.Select(p => new ResponseDto()
{
    customer_id = p.CustomerId, 
    office_debit_date = p.OfficeDebitDate.Value.ToString(),
    office_debit_id = p.OfficeDebitId.ToString(),
    office_debit_total = p.OfficeEnum == SomeEnum.ValueType ? p.OfficeAmount.ToString() : totalAmounts[p.OfficeDebitId].ToString(),
    payment_method = p.PaymentMethod.Value.ToString(),
}).ToList();
```

As it's possible to be seen `office_debit_total` is calculated depending on enum value, and here's dictionary that I'm using to get grouped data:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> totalAmounts = products
    .Where(p => p.ProductType == ProductType.ValueType)
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod }) 
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.OfficeDebitId, x => x.Sum(p => p.Amount));
```

But I have receiving following error message:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

I've tried writing `.ToLookup` instead of `.ToDictionary` but that didn't helped me..

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: You should either use simple key in `GroupBy` or composite key in `ToDictionary`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks for comment sir! Can you explain it further more, or provide an example? I'm really beginner at c# and most of the terms are not familiar to me

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Is it wrrong to Group by 3 properties `(OfficeDebitId, OfficeDebitDate, PaymentMethod)` and when it comes to `.ToDictionary` to pass only `(x => x.Key.OfficeDebitId..` or I should pass all 3 props that I'm grouping by again to `.ToDictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary has only `OfficeDebitId` as key then you need to group by only by it:

```
 var totalAmounts = products
    .Where(p => p.ProductType == ProductType.ValueType)
    .GroupBy(p =>  p.OfficeDebitId) 
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(p => p.Amount));
```

or use full anonymous object as key:

```
var totalAmounts = products
    .Where(p => p.ProductType == ProductType.ValueType)
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod }) 
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(p => p.Amount));
```

Or with value tuple as key:

```
var totalAmounts = products
        .Where(p => p.ProductType == ProductType.ValueType)
        .GroupBy(p => (p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod)) 
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(p => p.Amount));
```

Comment: what if I need to group by all those 3 properties? that I should use object as a key?

Comment: @MateuszRek Yes, the second option shows how to achieve that. You can use anonymous types as keys cause they [implement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types#remarks) the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in terms of the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the properties, so you will be able to lookup by creating new instance of anonymous type in the same method. If you need the dictiobary somewhere outside you will need to introduce a new type(or value tuple) for key.

Comment: Now I get error `'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collectiontions.Generic ....'` to `System.Collections.Generics.Dictionary<string, decimal>`

Comment: @GuruStron you cannot use anonymous as dictionary key.

Comment: @MateuszRek What's not working in the solution provided by me?

Comment: @DeepakMishra Same error as in Guru solution Now I get error `'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collectiontions.Generic ....'` to `System.Collections.Generics.Dictionary<string, decimal>`

Comment: But i have use `var totalamounts`

Comment: @DeepakMishra why?

Comment: @MateuszRek what is the type of `Amount`?

Comment: @GuruStron because it automatically gets it at compile time.

Comment: @GuruStron decimal

Comment: @MateuszRek change direct type declaration to `var` fixed the samples.

Comment: @DeepakMishra It runs on my machine(with my own type) with `var` perfectly. `var xx = x.GroupBy(x => new { x.MakeId, x.Name}).ToDictionary(x =>x.Key);` and `xx.ContainsKey( new {MakeId =1, Name = ""})`.

Comment: @GuruStron it is not useful to use a dictionary of anonymous types as you will not be able to return that dictionary as a return type. You would have to convert it to object, if you want to use it from a different function.

Comment: @DeepakMishra Dictionaries not always needed to be returned and I wrote about nessesity to define type/use value tuple if dictionary needed outside on my comment)

Comment: @GuruStron OK, anyway you answered a little later than my answer and it has almost the same content. I am just saying that anonymous types as a dictionary key is not a good practice. Many times you would like to encapsulate the code of dictionary creation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> totalAmounts = products
    .Where(p => p.ProductType == ProductType.ValueType)
    .GroupBy(p => p.OfficeDebitId) 
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(p => p.Amount));
```

You might need it in this way (You can use value tuple):

```
  Dictionary<(string OfficeDebitId, System.DateTime? OfficeDebitDate, Enumerations.PaymentMethod? PaymentMethod), decimal> totalAmounts = products
        .Where(p => p.ProductType == ProductType.ValueType)
        .GroupBy(p => new { p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod }) 
        .ToDictionary(x => (x.Key.OfficeDebitId, x.Key.OfficeDebitDate, x.Key.PaymentMethod ), x => x.Sum(p => p.Amount));
```

Comment: can you provide example with tuple?

Comment: the example is provided with the `ValueTuple`. Tihis is ValueTuple only `(x.Key.OfficeDebitId, x.Key.OfficeDebitDate, x.Key.PaymentMethod )`

Comment: @MateuszRek If you are looking for the type of totalAmounts it is `Dictionary<( string OfficeDebitId, string OfficeDebitDate, string PaymentMethod ), decimal>`

Comment: PaymentMethod is Enumeration, that is problem maybe?

Comment: in that case you can replace `string` with the type of PaymentMehod

Comment: is it wrrong to Group by 3 properties (OfficeDebitId, OfficeDebitDate, PaymentMethod) and `.ToDictionary` only `OfficeDebitId` ?