# Dictionary cannot convert from '<anonymous type>'

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Here's my code:

```
var groupedDataDictionary = products
    .Where(p => p.ProductType == ProductType.ValueType)
    .GroupBy(p => (p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(p => p.Amount)); 

var result = products.Select(p => new ResponseDto()
    {
        customer_id = p.CustomerId, 
        office_debit_date = p.OfficeDebitDate.Value.ToString(),
        office_debit_id = p.OfficeDebitId.ToString(),
        office_debit_total = groupedDataDictionary[new { p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod }].Sum().ToString(), // this line causes error
        payment_method = p.PaymentMethod.Value.ToString(),
    }).ToList();
```

When assiging `office_debit_total` on that line it says:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from  `'<anonymous type: string
>   OfficeDebiId, System.DateTime? OfficeDebitDate,
>   Enumerations.PaymentMethod? PaymentMethod>'`  to  `'(string
>   OfficeDebitId, System.DateTime? OfficeDebitDate,
>   Enumerations.PaymentMethod? PaymentMethod)'`

Comment: I recommend using a Tuple for the key.

Comment: @John can you provide an example, how ? Thanks

Comment: or using value tuple syntax  `GroupBy(p => (p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod))`

Comment: Isn't this question similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61712856/dictionary-groupings-and-sum-causes-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-a ?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that was another issue, couldn't add duplicate keys and that's solved

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I'm using tuple syntax while grouping, issue is when I'm invoking it below in select on office_debit_total line, it underlines whole line with error message that I've provided.

Comment: Your dict keys are tuples, and you are trying to use an anonymous class as a key

Comment: You should use either `Tuples` or `Anonymous Types`, but do not combine them. If you use anonymous types for groupping (`GroupBy(p => new { p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod })`) do you get an error? Also I see that `groupedDataDictionary` already contains aggregated data. Therefore when creating Dto you should write: `office_debit_total = groupedDataDictionary[new { p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod }].ToString(),` (I deleted `Sum()` method invocation).

Comment: @IliarTurdushev I'm using `Touple` syntax for grouping how should I wrote a `office_debit_total` than ? Thanks for help sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either `Tuples` or `Anonymous Types`, but do not combine them. If you want to use `Tuples` for keys then you should also use `Tuples` to get dictionary values by keys:

```
var result = products.Select(p => new ResponseDto()
    {
        customer_id = p.CustomerId, 
        office_debit_date = p.OfficeDebitDate.Value.ToString(),
        office_debit_id = p.OfficeDebitId.ToString(),

        // Here you should use Tuple to get value by Key.
        office_debit_total = groupedDataDictionary[(p.OfficeDebitId, p.OfficeDebitDate, p.PaymentMethod)].ToString(),

        payment_method = p.PaymentMethod.Value.ToString(),
    }).ToList();
```

Also note that I deleted invocation of the method `Sum()`, because dictionary `groupedDataDictionary` already contains aggregated data: `x.Sum(p => p.Amount)`.